# PDF print a password-protected page (ideally by making wkhtmltopdf use a cookie)

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize, wget, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to print a password-protected page to PDF with `wkhtmltopdf`, but I can't load a (working) cookie, meaning I always just print the "log in" page.

#### Saving the cookie post-login

The following code works as expected: If I log in, I can view the proper pages, whether I've loaded from the cookie, or entered my login information:

```
class PrintPages(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.browser = mechanize.Browser()
        self.cj = mechanize.MozillaCookieJar()
        self.browser.set_cookiejar(self.cj)
        self.login("cookies.txt")

    def login(self, cookie_jar):
        """ Log in, save cookie if doesn't exist. Otherwise, load cookie. """
        if os.path.isfile(cookie_jar):
            self.cj.load(cookie_jar, ignore_discard=True, ignore_expires=True)
        else:
            self.browser.open(self.login_url)

            self.browser.select_form(name="loginform")
            self.browser["username"] = self.username
            self.browser["password"] = getpass.getpass()

            self.browser.submit()
            self.cj.save(cookie_jar, ignore_discard=True, ignore_expires=True)
```

#### (cookies.txt)

```
    # Netscape HTTP Cookie File
    # http://www.netscape.com/newsref/std/cookie_spec.html
    # This is a generated file!  Do not edit.

sub.example.com  FALSE   /   TRUE        JSESSIONID  B8307A77925DB287B0346C728BBF8F24
```

---

However, telling either `wget` or `wkhtmltopdf` to load the cookies gives me the login page.

```
$ wget -p --load-cookies cookies.txt sub.example.com/page.html
$ wkhtmltopdf --cookie-jar cookies.txt sub.example.com/page.html page.pdf
```

What gives? Ideally any solution that allows me to print to PDF would be ideal, but I'm curious what's going on here.

---

I'm using:

- `wkhtmltopdf` version  0.9.9
- `mechanize`: version 0.2.5

Comment: Did you ever come right with this? I'm trying to do the same thing. I don't think that `wkhtmltopdf` works with the Netscape format cookies used by `wget` and `curl`. See [this issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1668).

Comment: I unfortunately did not. My hackish solution was to just `POST` login information on every password-protected page. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a solution to your specific problem of the cookies, but what we have done to print pdfs with permissions is:

1. Expose a separate view with no log in authentication.
2. Create a single use token for the pdf to be generated.
3. In the view with out authentication, ensure that the key is correct, and has not been use yet. If the token is valid, then return the html to convert into a pdf.
4. If your view needs to know which user is requesting the pdf (to customise the page in some way) you can store the user id along with the token in the database.

We are looking for a better way of dong this, but it works for us so far.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Yeah, in my specific case, I've resorted to just `POST`ing the username and password to a redirecting URL, but it still doesn't solve the cookie issue in general.

Comment: @Giles Smith: Any means did you guys figure out to password protect pdf using wkhtmltopdf ?